# How to get only two fields data from database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got code like this which displays every record that got using KEY_CODE. But i want to display records having only KEY_CODE and KEY_NAME which i inserted. What i need to do?

```
else {
    mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION}, 
    KEY_CODE + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
    null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: My God RameshLal So cheap

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
else {
    mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION}, 
    KEY_CODE + " like '%" + inputText + "%' AND " + KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputName + "%'", null,
    null, null, null, null);
}
```

If you want a exact match for Code and Name don´t use LIKE use =

```
else {
    mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION}, 
    KEY_CODE + " = '" + inputText + "' AND " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + inputName +"'", null,
    null, null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
else {
    mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION}, 
    KEY_CODE + " like '%" + inputTextForKEY_CODE + "%' AND" + KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputTextForKEY_NAME + "%'" , null,
    null, null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can build logical expressions with AND or OR.

If you have to inputs that you want to match to the respective fields (i.e., *both* must match), you should use AND:

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE,
                    new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION },
                    KEY_CODE + " LIKE ? AND " + KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[] { "%"+inputText+"%", "%"+inputName+"%" },
                    null, null, null, null);
```

If you have a single input that could match in either field, you should use OR:

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE,
                    new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION },
                    KEY_CODE + " LIKE ? OR " + KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[] { "%"+inputText+"%", "%"+inputText+"%", },
                    null, null, null, null);
```

Please note that you should always use parameters (`?`) for string values to avoid formatting problems and [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).